# Oracle dirty read

Tags: php, oracle, isolation-level, database-locking, rowlocking

I'm new using Oracle database 11g.

I was testing table and row locks using SQL Developer.

I have a row in my table like this:

- id : 1
- desc: 'abc'

I did an update without commit to change the field `desc` to `'zxc'`. In another session I did a select that returned the old record:

- id : 1
- desc: 'abc'

I was thinking that it would give me an error or something else because I don't want to see old data.

Finally when I commited in the other session I executed again the query in the second session and returned me the commited data.

How can I prevent old data read?

UPDATE:

I read about the sql "SELECT FOR UPDATE" and it prevents to get the row that was not commit but for example someone tell me about banks so i'm not sure is this approach has good performance and other issue is about lost connection without commit. Maybe i need to use a function or PLSQL to minimize the lost connection actually i'm using a PHP script ( Laravel Framework ).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to read this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10743/consist.htm

Comment: It's like editing a shared document.  Do you really want other users to see your changes before you hit `Save`?  A database commit is like saving a document.  Changes should only become visible to the world once you've explicitly stated that you approve the changes with a commit.  You can change the isolation level (read uncommitted) to change that behavior, but with a database like Oracle, I can't think of a single good reason to ever do that.

Comment: i expect the sql would give me an error. only get the row after a commit or rollback

Comment: @user2876735 Imagine how that would work in a bank transaction environment. Everything has to stop while one row is inserted. The system doesn't know which client's account will be affected, so EVERYTHING has to stop until "commit" or "rollback." Very little work would be possible in that kind of world.

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing normal "read committed" behavior. Commit means "I'm ready to let the rest of the world see the results of my transaction". If you don't commit it then it doesn't count as being there yet for any other database sessions. What you're calling "old data" is the latest committed data.

What would be bad would be if you could see the update before it was committed, that's what "read uncommitted" isolation level is. Transactions exist so that you can make changes to the database atomically so that queries view consistent state, not half-baked changes.

For instance, there might be two tables, an Orders table and a Line Items table, where the Orders table has a total for all the line items, and when I add a line item I want to update the Order for it in the same transaction so that the total reflects the new line item. I don't want the other users to be able to see either the change to the Orders row or the new line item without also seeing the other change, I want both changes to become visible together, so I make the changes within a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

There are very good reasons to read only committed data. One simple example may suffice to convince you that what you think you want is in fact a bad idea.

One reason to commit only at the end of a transaction, and not after each row update or insert, is to facilitate the entry of data with referential integrity constraints, where the constraints are checked only at the end of a transaction. Say a new department has been created, and it has a manager. You create a new row in the "departments" table, but that requires a manager value. You create the "manager" row in the "employees" table, but that requires a department. Which do you do first? Answer - it doesn't matter, since the integrity is checked only at the end of the transaction (inserts into both tables).

Now imagine you insisted to see uncommitted changes. The new department has been added to "departments", but it has NULL for manager, in a NOT NULL constrained column. Do you REALLY want to see that? You can probably come up yourself with three different ways in which this would cause serious problems in your applications.

(I skipped over subtleties here like deferred constraints, which is how scenarios like the one above are possible - that's not the point of my answer.)